# Intersection between two ADF GraphicsLayer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, map-service, arcgis-web-adf

I know how to intersect features from a ADF Geometry with a map ADF GraphicsLayer, but this requires me to have **ONE LAYER** on the map and then use a spatial filter on it.

If I have two GraphicsLayer which are NOT on the map, but they are the result of a query themselves, how can I intersect them and show the result?

I can't add one of them to the map because I can't interfere with it, this should be done in memory and not prompted to the user nor messing with the TableOfContents

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned because there has been no activity on it, and the asker has not logged in to this site, in nearly 2 years.  Consequently, I propose that it be closed.